# Sorting a dict in Python with multiple values

Tags: python, python-3.x

Lets say I have 2 dicts like

```
A = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':2}
B = {'a':5, 'b':7, 'c':6}
```

I want to sort dict `A` based on value of dict `A`. If there the value is same, it must use the value from B to resolve the sorting.
Eg: For keys 'b' and 'c', with same values in dict `A`, it must use values 7 and 6 from dict `B` to resolve it.

Comment: what is your expected result? What if b and c is not present in dict B?

Comment: You can ignore such cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `a` and `b` both have same keys:

```
a = {'a':1, 'b':0, 'c':2}
b = {'a':5, 'b':77, 'c':6}

dict(sorted(a.items(), key=lambda x: ( x[1], b[x[0]] ), reverse=True))
```

Comment: It will be safer to use get method from dict on b, here to pick values from b